# Exception Unhandled system.invalidOperationException 'The connection was not closed the connection current stste is open

Tags: c#

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OrderIdTb.Text == "" || CustId.Text == "" || CustName.Text == "" || TotAmount.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill The data Correctly");
    }
    else                  
    {
        Con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ProductTbl Values(" + OrderIdTb.Text + "," + CustId.Text + "," + CustName.Text + "," + orderdate.Text + "," + TotAmount.Text + ")", Con) ;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Order Added  Successfully ");
        populate();
        Con.Close();
                    
        try
        {

        }
        catch 
        {
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (Con.State != ConnectionState.Open()) Con.Open()`

Comment: You have **dangerous** SQL injection going there, use parameters instead. Do not cache the connection, create it when you need it and dispose with `using`

Answer (score 0):

it's good habit to write finally block and within that you have close all opened sql connections and try to use Using loop to run the query.

Eg:

```
SqlConnection sqlconn= null;
   SqlCommand sqlcmd= null;
   SqlTransaction sqlTrans= null;
   SqlDataReader sqlReader= null;
   try
   {
      sqlconn = new SqlConnection("conn string");
      sqlconn.Open();
---- Query ---
---- Query ---
---- Query ---
sqlconn.Close()
   }
catch(exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
if(sqlReader !=null)
{
sqlReader.close();
sqlReader = null;
}
if(sqlTrans != null)
{
sqlTrans.Dispose();
sqlTrans = null;
}
if(sqlcmd != null)
{
sqlcmd.Dispose();
sqlcmd = null;
}
if( sqlconn != null)
{
sqlconn.Close();
sqlconn = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new connection for each function. Don't try to reuse a database connection, it always ends badly.

```
   using (var con = new SqlConnection(....)){
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ProductTbl Values(" + OrderIdTb.Text + "," + CustId.Text + "," + CustName.Text + "," + orderdate.Text + "," + TotAmount.Text + ")", Con) ;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Order Added  Successfully ");
        populate();
   } //Then end of the using block closes the connection safely, even if there is an error.
```